# When hovering parent div, change bg color of child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, this

I have the following setup:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to change all the background color of all of them at the same time, when the mouse is hovering over any one of them. I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('.parent').hover( function(){
       $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
    },
     function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
 });
 </script>
```

But, the color is not "showing through" the children `<div>`s.

Is there a way to choose the descendents of "this". I have many of these sets in a row, so I think I need to use "this" so I don't have the call each parent by id. I'm thinking something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('.parent').hover( function(){
       $(this "div").css('background-color', 'gray');
    },
     function(){
      $(this "div").css('background-color', 'red');
    });
 });
 </script>
```

But, can't quite get it to work - all the examples on jquery.com use the id selector... none use "this".

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for: http://api.jquery.com/children/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you already tried .children()?

[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 5):

If you're not targeting IE6, no need to use JavaScript, pure CSS will do the trick:

```
.parent, .child {
    background-color:red;
}

.parent:hover, .parent:hover .child {
    background-color:gray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `.find()`

```
$(this).find('div').css('background-color','red');
```

http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 $(function() {
    $('.parent').hover( function(){
       $(this).children("div").css('background-color', 'gray');
    },
     function(){
       $(this).children("div").css('background-color', 'red');
    });
 });
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/zt9M6/

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$()` with mixed arguments - it's either got to be a string as a selector (`div`), or just a DOM element (`this`). To select all `div`s within the context of `this`, try calling it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('.parent').hover( function(){
       $("div", this).css('background-color', 'gray');
    },
     function(){
      $("div", this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
 });
 </script>
```

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 0):

Do it with CSS classes

```
.parent .child{
    background-color: red;
}

.hoverstyle .child{
    background-color: gray;
}

$(.parent')hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hoverstyle"):
},
function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hoverstyle");
});
```